# After enabling new product, all the other products disappear from frontend

Tags: debugging, magento, magento-1.7

I've faced a problem I've never experienced before. One of my clients are trying to add new prodcts to their magento store, but as soon as we change its status to enabled, all other products are disappearing from the category it's in, except one, but that's not even the product we added. So nor the new product showing up, nor the old ones...After changing the product back on to disabled, everything gets back to normal order...

Very weird problem

I've tried rebuilding the indexes, flushing the cache and so on, but nothing worked. Any ideas guys? It's a Magento ver. 1.7.0.2

Thanks for any help.

*update
this is the first time my client tried to add products after his site was moved to a new server. The error logs state autoload.php can't open imagemagick.php

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Comment: 2014-01-17T12:59:41+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Imagick.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/shopvill/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 93

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing imagemagick on the server, the problem disappeared. Thanks for the support